# How to define a _find query in couchdb mango with field names that start with dollar sign ($)

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-mango

Many years ago we launched a project to manage semi-structured information for research projects. We used CouchDB, and at that time it was convenient for us to call the mandatory fields of entries starting with a dollar sign ($)
{"id": 123, "$type": "entry", "$owners": ["somebody"],...  }
I have to clarify that Mango did not exist for CouchDB at that time. Now I would like to run the query to find all the entries of my database which "$type" is "entry". But Mango throws an error because  "$type" is not an operator.

{"$type": "entry"}

Does somebody know a way to circumvent this problem that does not require to fix the names on my database?

Is there a way to escape the dollar sign in the names?

Comment: There's a possible solution [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59654609/13860). I wonder if that works for you?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59654609/13860), as well as on this [CouchDB GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-documentation/issues/506#issuecomment-598954510), this is possible by escaping the `$` character:

> ... you can escape the dollar sign with `\\$keyname`.

Answer (score 0):

From the github issue, I got this answer, and I confirm it works.

`Looks like you can escape the dollar sign with \\$keyname.`

In my case, `{"\\$type": "entry"}`