# creating a selector for document's name

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-3.x

I am using CouchDB v3.1.0 and am trying to create a selector for [`/{db}/_find`](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#post--db-_find) to find documents named "foobar".

In the docs section [`1.3.6.1.1 Selector Basics`](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#selector-basics), there are several mentions of a `$title`:

> ```json
> "selector": {
>   "$title": "Live And Let Die"
> }
> ```

However, when I try to use it like so:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
http://my-host-machine:5984/testdb/_find \
-d '{"selector":{"$title":"foobar"}}' --user admin | jq .
```

The following error message is output:

```json
{
  "error": "invalid_operator",
  "reason": "Invalid operator: $title"
}
```

What **does** work is using the `_id` field in the selector: `'{"selector":{"_id":"foobar"}}'`

However, this doesn't feel correct to use a document's unique identifier.  My questions:

- Does `$title` work?  (Am I just using it incorrectly)
- Is `_id` an appropriate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a name field has a dollar sign (`$`) prefix, CouchDB interprets it as an [operator](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#operators). `$title` however isn't a valid operator and the related `selector` samples in the documentation seem to be wrong.

On the other hand, when you need to select documents by a field that is preceded by a dollar sign (`$`), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57036999/2358409) may be useful.

Comment: I opened a [PR](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-documentation/pull/591) to fix the `$title` and it was merged.

Comment: @Intrastellar Explorer: That went quick, great initiative!